# Serializing/deserializing in memory of a process

Tags: java, c++, serialization

I am considering to use Thrift, Protobuff, FlatBuffers for serializing/deserializing data from C++ to Java and vice versa. Most of the implementations that I see involves a client/server architecture and it is two different processes sending data back and forth and not in-memory of a process, which I am looking for. 
Can it be done by any of these, which will allow me to avoid using JNI?

Comment: JNI (or JNA) **is** how you would access "in-memory of a process" with Java. You might also consider [jeromq](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) / [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/). The jeromq features page notes *tcp:// protocol and inproc:// is compatible with zeromq.*

Answer (score 0):

Using Thrift you could use TMemoryBuffer and then read from the buffer and write to shared memory (involves copying that data though).
Read here: [Using Thrift for IPC-Communication via shared Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546348/using-thrift-for-ipc-communication-via-shared-memory)